# When VPN is connected it disconnects other clients connections to the server

Tags: vpn, internet, putty, ubuntu-20.04, openconnect

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the tutorial here to install and connect to a VPN, which worked brilliantly. I'm using PuTTy and WinScp to connect. After connecting using PuTTy, I noticed that all other clients connected to the server get disconnected, and I can't connect again until I disconnect the VPN.

Please, what do I do as I need to execute some command while connected to the VPN. I'm running a load test on the website behind VPN.

Comment: which tutorial was that? there are common problems with VPN connections related to what they call split tunneling, but we can't really tell much about your configuration from the description. so is the VPN client configuration on your workstation, or the server? what VPN technology/client are you using (you would not usually call an SSH/SCP connection a vpn, though there are simillarities, ssh usually is just a session, whereas vpn operates at the system level and thus can affect all traffic).